# Deployment permission for an ANT user?

Tags: deployment, ant

I want to create a differet profile for my ANT user which will have only required permissions. This is required for new IT security policy of the organization when admin level access cannot be assigned to every user. I need to determine all required permissions to be assigned to this profile so that there is no issue with any deployment. Any suggestion or reference will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The three permissions needed are: "Customize Application", "Author Apex", and "API Enabled," as well as all related permissions, including "Modify All Data." This user will basically have almost full access to the system, but not be able to reset passwords or otherwise manage users.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try this out and run few test